# How do see logging of ssh command on ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, logging

I'm looking to execute a command remotely and observe the log of it on the remote machine.

Say I execute locally: `ssh app_81 ls /`

And on the `app_81` box I'd like to see the log of that command. However, I see only the log of the login, but not a log of the command being run:

`ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-81:/var/log$ ll -ltr | tail -n 3
-rw-rw-r--  1 root   utmp   292292 Apr  5 16:44 lastlog
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm     21000 Apr  5 19:10 auth.log
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm     21760 Apr  5 19:14 syslog
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-81:/var/log$ tail syslog
Apr  5 19:10:16 ip-10-0-1-81 dhclient[916]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.0.1.81 on eth0 to 10.0.1.1 port 67 (xid=0x23563ebf)
Apr  5 19:10:16 ip-10-0-1-81 dhclient[916]: DHCPACK of 10.0.1.81 from 10.0.1.1
Apr  5 19:10:16 ip-10-0-1-81 root: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/samba returned non-zero exit status 1
Apr  5 19:10:16 ip-10-0-1-81 dhclient[916]: bound to 10.0.1.81 -- renewal in 1651 seconds.
Apr  5 19:10:17 ip-10-0-1-81 systemd[1]: Started Session 1731 of user ubuntu.
Apr  5 19:10:40 ip-10-0-1-81 systemd[1]: Started Session 1732 of user ubuntu.
Apr  5 19:14:15 ip-10-0-1-81 systemd-timesyncd[20400]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Apr  5 19:14:25 ip-10-0-1-81 systemd-timesyncd[20400]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Apr  5 19:14:36 ip-10-0-1-81 systemd-timesyncd[20400]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Apr  5 19:14:46 ip-10-0-1-81 systemd-timesyncd[20400]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-81:/var/log$ tail auth.log
Apr  5 19:10:17 ip-10-0-1-81 sshd[10352]: Disconnected from 10.0.0.80 port 43764
Apr  5 19:10:17 ip-10-0-1-81 sshd[10320]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ubuntu
Apr  5 19:10:17 ip-10-0-1-81 systemd-logind[1122]: Removed session 1731.
Apr  5 19:10:40 ip-10-0-1-81 sshd[10367]: Accepted publickey for ubuntu from 10.0.0.80 port 43766 ssh2: RSA SHA256:OhHSoIWEYhfqaIYaE5tNvgZMPY3AEYgJDv4c1H/Gxm8
Apr  5 19:10:40 ip-10-0-1-81 sshd[10367]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Apr  5 19:10:40 ip-10-0-1-81 systemd-logind[1122]: New session 1732 of user ubuntu.
Apr  5 19:10:41 ip-10-0-1-81 sshd[10401]: Received disconnect from 10.0.0.80 port 43766:11: disconnected by user
Apr  5 19:10:41 ip-10-0-1-81 sshd[10401]: Disconnected from 10.0.0.80 port 43766
Apr  5 19:10:41 ip-10-0-1-81 sshd[10367]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ubuntu
Apr  5 19:10:41 ip-10-0-1-81 systemd-logind[1122]: Removed session 1732.`

Is that not logged at all, or am I not looking in the right place?

Comment: Have you tried using another shell?
zsh is better at logging commands issued by several sessions into the history file

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behaviour.  SSH does not log commands that are issued (aside from use of `su` to change user.

If you wish to have the commands logged, then you should use sudo for all commands.

BASH history for the user will capture the activity also.